# How do I send OpenCV Mat as a putExtra to Android Intent?

Tags: android, opencv, parcelable

I am trying to send either CvCameraViewFrame or Mat to another activity, but they don't implement Serializable or Parcelable and creating a wrapper class for them just to use it once seems like an overkill.
How do I proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have used fragments instead of activities and get/set common `Mat` present in container Activity from fragments.

If there is a need to stick with multiple activities, assuming it's within process, options are

1. **Sharing** - Use  global `Application` subclass to get/set the `Mat` preferably in some thing like `HashMap<String, WeakReference<Mat>>` and passing HashMap's key string across activities([1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/I1swY6FlbPI/gGkY8mt8_IQJ)). Make sure you stores a strong reference to the `Mat` before child activity completes `onResume()`, or else `Mat` could be garbage collected.
2. **Copying** - Using `getNativeObjAddr`([2](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#getNativeObjAddr()))  and pass the `long` address value as part of invoking Intent. Child activity would recreate the `Mat` with the native address([3](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#Mat(long))). Cloning `Mat` in child is necessary since parent activity could be killed any time after `onResume` of child activity is completed.

Sample below.

```
// In parent activity
Mat img = ...;
long addr = img.getNativeObjAddr();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.putExtra( "myImg", addr );
startActivity( intent );

//In child activity
long addr = intent.getLongExtra("myImg", 0);
Mat tempImg = new Mat( addr );
Mat img = tempImg.clone();
```

Comment: What is tempImg(addr) ?

Answer (score 0):

@Kiran is right.

You should get instance of Matrix using its native address.

```
long frameAddress = intent.getLongExtra("extra_name", 0);
Mat m = new Mat(frameAddress);
```