# how to send a list of opencv Mat via Android intent

Tags: android, opencv, android-intent

I have a list of openCV Mat and trying to pass all my list from Activity1 to Activity2 but I don't know how to implement it. I already saw this [link for send only 1 mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060376/how-do-i-send-opencv-mat-as-a-putextra-to-android-intent)  but sending Mat one by one doesn't seem to be a solution.

```
Intent i = new Intent( Activity1.this, Activity2.class );
i.putExtra("someExtra", someExtra);
i.putExtra("list", ArrayList<Mat> ); ///I wan't to do something like that.
startActivity(i);
Activity1.this.finish();


// Activity2
getIntent().getExtra("list");   // get my list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to send the primitive objects that make up your Mat object and reconstruct the Mat on the otherside.

I have not done this myself, but looking at the javadoc there are a few options:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Mat.html

One could be to use the native address and the address constructor. i.e:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#%3Cinit%3E(long)
&
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#getNativeObjAddr()

use `getNativeObjAddr` on each of your Mat's (an `Int`) and store a `List<Int>` in your `Intent`. Then on the otherside recreate a `List<Mat>` by using the `Mat(Int)` constructor.

If this doesn't work, look at how you create your `Mat` objects, if you use a `byte[]` then again, try sending that in the Intent instead.

Comment: i use a List<Long> with getNativeObjAddr instead of List<Int>, it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make `Mat` class implements parcelable interface, [this is an official link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable).

After that, below codes should work:

```
Intent i = new Intent( Activity1.this, Activity2.class );
i.putExtra("someExtra", someExtra);
i.putExtra("list", ArrayList<Mat> )
```

To get data, use:

```
 ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list");
```

Comment: Mat is not my class, so I need to create a MatParcelable class and extends from Mat and use "natifObj" as my attr ? but "natifObj" is final